Why does summary of bam model not work when using m=1 (generalised additive models)?
I'm trying to use bam() and method="fREML" to speed up my analyses.
require(mgcv)
require(gratia)
require(brms)
require(DHARMa)
require(marginaleffects)

mode11 <- bam(Met1 ~ s(Timepoint, k=7) + s(Timepoint, by=subject, k=7) + s(subject, bs="re"), data=df, method="fREML")

model2 <- bam(Met1 ~ s(Timepoint, k=7) + s(Timepoint, by=subject, k=7, m=1) + s(subject, bs="re"), data=df, method="fREML")

I noticed the models above run, but when I try and get a summary for model2, I get the following error
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'chol': non-conformable arrays

Why might this be (m=1 is affecting it, but not sure why the above error)? A summary of a gam()  with m=1 works fine.
EDIT: cannot find another example where this applies, so presume its data specific. But not sure how to assess model2 output to understand why summary(model2) doesn't work. dput(df) below.
structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("1", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "16", "17", "19", 
"21", "22", "25", "26", "28", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "48", "50", "51", "52", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "61", "65", "71"), class = "factor"), Timepoint = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L
), Met1 = c(0.012461309, 0.01794298, 0.003863203, -0.006398583, 
0.001760362, 0.000870293, 0.000830637, -0.014258656, -0.01946732, 
0.00389311, 0.000199752, -0.0122629, 0.007792022, 0.007019363, 
0.006641794, 0.012690831, 0.004881705, -0.004663227, 0.002341043, 
-0.008827367, -0.009172269, 0.038058982, -0.002204742, -0.003488286, 
0.004832194, -0.00137924, -0.016501518, 0.006870124, 0.011860637, 
0.005993393, -0.004560137, -0.007139575, 0.000783146, 0.026054272, 
0.000494855, 0.008204079, -0.011764013, -0.006389326, 0.008017244, 
0.004591451, 0.012983199, 0.010973351, 0.005136924, 0.014092113, 
0.002394753, 0.022453531, 0.012407455, 0.001519177, 0.000155242
)), row.names = c(NA, 49L), class = "data.frame")


as a start, you can work around this by specifying summary(model2, re.test = FALSE)

Just a note. By reducing k to 6, summary works: s(Timepoint, by=subject, k=6, m=1).

@MarcoSandri, that's weird, you're right.

An incomplete answer, after spending some time with traceback() and debug() (debugging the functions mgcv:::summary.gam, mgcv:::reTest, mgcv:::recov).

the first deviation between model 1 and model 2 comes here. If re.test is TRUE, according to ?summary.gam, tests are performed

for random effect terms (including any term with a zero dimensional null space)

when m=1 (rather than the default value of 2), the null spaces of the smooths in the second term (this formula term decomposes into 7 subject-specific smooths) are all zero, so these terms will be tested for model2 but not model1. As a first step, then, you can use re.test = FALSE in summary() to work around the problem (provided you don't need the results of those tests).



the precise point of failure is here. Working backward and comparing the bam fit to a gam fit, it seems that the problem stems from the fact that the $R component has 56 rows for the gam model, matching the total number of coefficients (and the expectation of the machinery of summary.gam), but only 49 for the bam model — leading to the matrix non-conformity.

It's hard to track down what the $R component is, exactly (I think it's the R component of a QR decomposition), and why its dimension differs between gam and bam — I assume it has something to do with how the RE (bs="re") term is treated, since omitting those coefficients would shrink dimensions from 56 to 49 ...
The plot thickens: @MarcoSandri points out that the problem goes away if k=6, in which case (debugging through) length(p) is only 49 rather than 56 [I'm not sure why ...] ... so the revised case where the problem happens is "there is at least one non-random term with null-space zero AND length(model$coefficients) != nrow(model$R)"
This seems to be a bug. ?bug.reports.mgcv says:

The ideal report consists of an email to
<mailto:simon.wood@r-project.org> with a subject line including
‘mgcv’ somewhere, containing

The results of running ‘sessionInfo’ in the R session where
the problem occurs. This provides platform details, R and
package version numbers, etc.




A brief description of the problem.




Short cut and paste-able code that produces the problem,
including the code for loading/generating the data (using
standard R functions like ‘load’, ‘read.table’ etc).
Any required data files. If you send real data it will only
be used for the purposes of de-bugging.
Of course if you have dug deeper and have an idea of what is
causing the problem, that is also helpful to know, as is any
suggested code fix. (Don't send a fixed package .tar.gz file,
however - I can't use this).


You could include a link to this question ...

thank you very much for this - I've sent a bug report to Prof Simon Wood and will update this post, hopefully, in due course.

This is a bug.
R is the R factor from the QR decomposition of the model matrix, X. In this case X is rank deficient and the trailing zero block of R has not been returned. That's a problem when computing p-values with more than one term treated as a random effect* (includes m=1 smooths, as the penalty null space is then zero dimensional). Fixed for 1.9-2. Meanwhile you could just use bam(...,discrete=TRUE). Or gam() if the real data set of interest is not too large.
(The example model is pretty statistically unstable, so I would not be giving much credence to the subject related p-values here, but presumably the real data set is much larger given you are using bam).
Simon W

the p-value computation distinction is really between terms where the penalty shrinks directly towards the null hypothesis being tested (e.g. random effects, m=1 terms), and terms where it doesn't (e.g. m>1).


and is (was) the bam/gam difference that gam returns the trailing zero block in R while bam doesn't/didn't?
